# Does Blitz3D use its own 3D engine or does it wrap OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, blitzmax

How does [Blitz3D](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Products/blitz3d.php) work? I mean internally, does it use OpenGL with basic wrappers or it using some open source 3D engine that itself wraps OpenGL?

Comment: earok's answer is right on the money. I just want to comment, Blitz3D was a great development tool when I was first learning 3D game programming. It's still a good learning tool because the API is so simple, but it is way out of date by now.

Comment: I removed your follow up question; this is a Q&A site, so if you want to ask another question you should post another entire question rather than edit this one. You are more likely to get better answers that way, and you'll also improve the searchability of the site for everybody else.

Answer (score 5):

Blitz3D's engine is based on DirectX 7. It does not uses OpenGL at all.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to earok: BlitzMax was first dialect of Blitz that was using OpenGL.

Comment: yeah from what i saw when downloading Blitz there are glut lib's